# Using v.net.path to give route that spends less CO2?

Tags: grass-gis, routing

i am trying to calculate the route that emits less CO2 (for a master thesis). I have a line layer with a field with CO2 and Lenght (and of course, with all the other fields like id speed etc):

[image]

The goal is to instead of calculating the less cost route, i want that the v.net.path gives me the route that spends less CO2, its more or less the same anyway.

What do i need to put in each field of v.net.path?

->"Input vector line layer (arc)" - just add the layer with the road network (and with the CO2 information per line).

->"Centers point layer (nodes)" - i created a nodes layer with v.net.nodes i assumed this is what the field requires.

->"Name of file containing start and end points" - ok, it has to be in a certain format, can you please write an example? I used this (json file): "id -932241 4859815 -931884 4858560" is it correct? (EPSG: 3857)

-> etc

ADVANCED PARAMETERS
-> "Arc type" 
-> the next two choose "CO2"

etc

I think that the problem is in defining the start and end point.

I run the v.net.path it runs but gives me no results. Maybe i should use another coordinate system?

Is there any example out there (with everything WELL explained)?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.net.path.html) reference?

Comment: Yes. But I think the problem is on this field "Name of file containing start and end points" i guess i am not using the right coordinates. And what to put in id?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this tool, but what does happen if you format the text file in this way: `2 x y`, where `2` is the `node_layer` and `x` and `y` are the coordinates of interest? I don't know if it is correct, but you can look [this](http://www.ing.unitn.it/~zatelli/environmental_data_management/Network_analysis_with_GRASS.pdf) tutorial, starting from page 13.

Comment: Thank you, that tutorial might be very useful (your suggestion didnt work :|)

Comment: Well i started using the GRASS stand alone version, and I figure out how to do what i want! Thanks for the help. (there you can PICK manually the start and end)

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution because my understanding of the problem was very limited. It could be of interest sharing the solution with the community, writing it as a new answer, in order to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

if you have the same question just use the Vector Network Analysis Tool from GRASS GIS 7.2.1, its more simple because you can pick manually the start and end point.

one problem it can occur is that it may not find the route for some start-end points so you need to use v.clean.break in order to clean the network.

Just follow this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McOrMauPc_I
and this:
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/wxGUI.vnet.html

But as i was working with numbers (CO2) you need to adapt this (you have to do this step before starting the analysis):

```
v.category in=roads out=myroads opt=add cat=1 layer=3 type=line
v.db.addtable myroads layer=3 col="cat integer,label varchar(43)"  
v.to.db myroads layer=3 qlayer=1 opt=query qcolumn=label columns=label
```

Into something like this

```
v.category in=roads out=myroads opt=add cat=1 layer=3 type=line
v.db.addtable myroads layer=3 col="cat integer,CO2 double"   v.to.db
myroads layer=3 qlayer=1 opt=query qcolumn=double columns=double
```

"roads" is your original network

Comment: I`m having the same issue. What are the start and end points?